# How to find out, which network device is created by an USB port?

Tags: linux, networking, usb, network-interface, sysfs

I see a networking device in the USB bus: `lsusb` shows it well and it looks working well.

As a network device, it also generates a network interface. Yes, `ip link ls` shows them, and some of them is what I want.

*How to find out, which network interface is generated by which usb device?*